# How capture firebase notification in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do I receive notifications in the react app and not in the browser?

At moment I receive notifications on :

```
firebase-messaging-sw.js
```

[image]

code of firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');
var config = {
    apiKey: "myapikey",
    authDomain: "thank-you-posta.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://thank-you-posta.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "thank-you-posta",
    storageBucket: "thank-you-posta.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "403125505139"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow('http://localhost:7000/#/messages/')
  );
});
```

Code in Layout:

```
var config = {
        apiKey: "myapikey",
        authDomain: "thank-you-posta.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://thank-you-posta.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "thank-you-posta",
        storageBucket: "thank-you-posta.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "403125505139"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        messaging.getToken()
        .then(function(currentToken) {
            if (currentToken) {
                console.log(currentToken);
                _this.setState({
                    pushToken: currentToken
                });
                
            } else {
                // Show permission request.
                console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                // Show permission UI.
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      // ...
    });
```

My problem is that I want to receive notifications to make a dropdown with all the notifications in Layout.
Thx All.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show these notifications in your app then you have to create a notifications component in your app. The simplest way to do this is to use something like toaster https://github.com/tomchentw/react-toastr

Basically, you add a toaster snippet in your root component and then you feed toaster your notifications. It is unclear from your code where you are storing the notifications that you send to your service worker, but wherever they are just redirect them to toast. If you are creating new messages from the firebase console then redirect them to toast when you specify `.onMessage`

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      // the container bit below is from the toast demo in the link above
      container.success(payload, {
          closeButton: true,
        })
    });
```

Toaster is basically just a div at the top of your screen that disappears after a while. You can build your own solution. Toaster and other projects like it are just commonly used for this purpose.

If you want a custom drop-down component with all the notifications then you have to build it and style it like any other component. When the component is in place, save the messages to firebase/firestore database inside the `.onMessage` snippet above and then retrieve the message inside your new notifications component.

Comment: no. You don't understand my problem. I need to capture firebase notification. not in sw.js, but in the application (in my script)

Comment: Yes, I answered this question by saying you capture it in sw.js, save it to the database and then retrieve it from teh database in the notification component that you have to build. Create a new collection called notifications in you firebase database and save notifications there. If your notifications are being stored on the database anyway (instead of generated from the notification console) then you can skip the sw.js part.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by assigning functions to messaging `onMessageHandler` and `onBackgroundMessageHandler`. This is what you should write in your `firebase.js` file to listen and wait for incoming messages:

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

messaging.onMessageHandler = ((payload) => {
  // do something ...
});
messaging.onBackgroundMessageHandler = ((payload) => {
  // do something ...
});
```

I'm not sure if it solves it for you, but I hope it helps.